# オブジェクト指向で作成したアプリが起動時にエラーになります。

Tags: android, java, android-studio

下記のプログラムをスマホ上で実行すると起動と同時に終了してしまいます。コーディング時にはエラーが出ないのでどこに問題があるのか分かりません。原因を教えてくださる方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いします。
※MonsterはString型とImageView型のインスタンスフィールドを持つクラスです。

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    // イメージ取得
    ImageView fImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fireI);
    ImageView lImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.leafI);
    ImageView wImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.waterI);
    // コンストラクタ設定
    Monster f = new Monster("ヒトカゲ",fImage);
    Monster l = new Monster("フシギダネ",lImage);
    Monster w = new Monster("ゼニガメ",wImage);
}
```

Comment: これだけではわからないです。アプリが落ちた時にAndroidStudioにエラーが表示されるはずなので、そちらを確認してみてください。AndroidMonitorというタブを選ぶと出てくるはずです。参考画像では文字が白いですが、赤文字で表示されるのがエラーメッセージです。https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef6Kb.png

Comment: 私の環境ではデバッグ起動をした状態でLogcatを選ぶとExceptionが出てきます。AndroidMonito‌rが見あたらなければそちらで確かめると良いでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById()` はインスタンス変数の宣言時に行ってはいけません。
`onCreate`の中で実行するようにプログラムを修正すると良いでしょう。

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // イメージ取得
        ImageView fImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fireI);
        ImageView lImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.leafI);
        ImageView wImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.waterI);

        // コンストラクタ設定
        Monster f = new Monster("ヒトカゲ",fImage);
        Monster l = new Monster("フシギダネ",lImage);
        Monster w = new Monster("ゼニガメ",wImage);
   }
}
```